Spring Security- This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. when attempting to access localhost:8080 with Spring Security
Hi I am working on a Spring boot web application in which I am using Spring security and for views I am using JSP pages. when trying to access the pages configured with permitall() that is home page and login page I am getting this error on the browser and nothing is printed on the console. so after adding a logger, I got to know that the controller function is getting called repeatedly below is my code and console screenshot for reference can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?
Application.properties file for JSP pages
server.error.path=/error 
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

PageController
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/swadeshiBank/v1")
public class PageController {

    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PageController.class);


    private static final String loginPage = "login";


    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String homePage(){
        logger.info("Request Came to home :");
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public String getLoginPage(){
        logger.info("Request Came to login :");
        return loginPage;
    }

}

Security Configuration
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/", "/swadeshiBank/v1/", "/swadeshiBank/v1/login").permitAll() // Public pages
                .requestMatchers("/swadeshiBank/v1/account-details").authenticated() // Authenticated users
                .requestMatchers("/swadeshiBank/v1/admin").hasRole("ADMIN") // Admin users
                .requestMatchers("/swadeshiBank/v1/management").hasRole("MANAGER") // Manager users
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/swadeshiBank/v1/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/swadeshiBank/v1/login") // URL to submit the login form
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/swadeshiBank/v1/account-details", true)
                .permitAll()
            )
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swadeshiBank/v1/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/swadeshiBank/v1/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()
            );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build());
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin")
                .password("{noop}admin")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build());
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("manager")
                .password("{noop}manager")
                .roles("MANAGER")
                .build());
        return manager;
    }
}

Project Structure

Console Screenshot

Browser Screenshot

Can you please help me here? additionally, Current behaviour what I noticed when I type
http://localhost:8080/ in browser it takes me to http://localhost:8080/swadeshiBank/v1/login but I want the landing page should be http://localhost:8080/swadeshiBank/v1/ and login page should only appear when I click on login button.

When you set your spring-security logger to DEBUG, you can see that spring tries to access login.jsp as a secured resource, meaning it locks the file behind its security features.
Since the file-url /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp is not recognized by any request-matchers you defined, it is only allowed for authenticated users, as that is what you set for anyRequest() in your http.authorizeHttpRequests() lambda-function. This still allows the /login url to be accessed without authentication, but the request to the login.jsp file is getting blocked by spring. Whenever spring blocks a request, it redirects the user to the login-page. Since you re-routed the /login url to your custom endpoint, this would loop forever if there weren't a hard limit for the amount of redirects.
To solve your issue, it should suffice to add the /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp resource-endpoint to your request-matchers that have the permitAll() option, like so:

// Class and stuff above

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/", "/swadeshiBank/v1/", "/swadeshiBank/v1/login", "/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp").permitAll() // Public pages
                .requestMatchers("/swadeshiBank/v1/account-details").authenticated() // Authenticated users
                .requestMatchers("/swadeshiBank/v1/admin").hasRole("ADMIN") // Admin users
                .requestMatchers("/swadeshiBank/v1/management").hasRole("MANAGER") // Manager users
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )

// Your form-login-settings

// Your logout-settings

        return http.build();
    }

// Stuff below the method



Hi @Fi0x Thanks for the response. Can you help me understand as you mentioned that login.jsp file is getting locked and Spring wants me to login first as I have mentioned my own login URL so it is getting redirected again and again before accessing any JSP pages will that be possible if I show the home.jsp as a landing page and then click on Login button this login shows up as I want a few pages to be accessible before login appreciate your help. Thanks

You basically have to "whitelist" all the endpoints that you want to be accessible for public users, which you're already doing. But since your endpoints return the .jsp files, you also have to "whitelist" those. To do so, just add the path of the file within your resources-folder to the requestMatchers. This means you have to add WEB-INF/views/login.jsp, as I've shown in the example. To allow the other endpoints as well, you need to add their .jsp files as well. You can also put all the public files in a folder and just add the whole folder, which makes it easier and less confusing.
